# How to map each column of json array in kotlin

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, user-interface, mapping

greetings fellow pro coders,

I have a question regarding the mapping of each key/value of json array in kotlin. Below are my code.

```
                val startDate = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.startDate)
                val authstatus1 = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.authStatus1)
                val startDate1 = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.startDate1)
                val url = "https://appbsa.tabgdc.com/api/v3/me/history"

                val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireActivity())

                val stringRequest = object: StringRequest(
                    Method.GET, url,
                    Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                        println(response)
                        val jsonString = response
                        var map: Map<String, Any> = HashMap()
                        map = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, map.javaClass)
                        val authstatusTV = StringBuilder()
                        val startDateTV = StringBuilder()
                        val seqTV = StringBuilder()
                        val jsonObj = JSONObject(jsonString)
                        val jsonArray = jsonObj.optJSONArray("data")


                        if (jsonArray != null) {
                          for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                                val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                                val status = jsonObject.optString("status")
                                val regDt = jsonObject.optString("regDt")
                                val seq = jsonObject.optString("seq")
                                authstatusTV.append(status)
                                startDateTV.append(regDt)
                                seqTV.append(seq)
                            }
                            authstatus.text = authstatusTV.toString()
                            startDate.text = startDateTV.toString()
                            println(startDateTV.toString())
                        }
                        startDate.text = startDateTV.toString()
                    },
                    Response.ErrorListener {
                        println("Error!")
                    })
                {
                    override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                        headers["Authorization"] = MainActivity.GlobalVariable.tokenG
                        return headers
                    }
                }
                queue.add(stringRequest)
```

the result of the for loop is that I'm getting all the values inside the array. Here is the result of **println(startDateTV.toString())**

> 2022-08-23 03:50:36.00 +00002022-08-23 03:50:49.00 +00002022-08-23 03:51:36.00 +00002022-09-01 02:44:41.00 +00002022-09-01 02:46:32.00 +00002022-09-13 06:15:57.00 +00002022-10-06 03:49:53.00 +00002022-10-06 03:52:19.00 +00002022-10-06 03:58:26.00 +00002022-10-06 04:06:21.00 +00002022-10-06 06:21:06.00 +00002022-10-06 06:27:13.00 +00002022-10-06 06:28:05.00 +00002022-10-06 06:40:52.00 +00002022-10-06 06:50:38.00 +00002022-10-06 07:02:27.00 +00002022-10-06 07:22:52.00 +00002022-10-06 07:23:55.00 +00002022-10-06 07:26:16.00 +00002022-10-06 07:30:23.00 +0000

How to get all the results one by one using loop?

Answer (score 0):

put the println inside the for loop

```
                  var text = ""
                    if (jsonArray != null) {
                      for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                            val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                            val status = jsonObject.optString("status")
                            val regDt = jsonObject.optString("regDt")
                            val seq = jsonObject.optString("seq")
                            authstatusTV.append(status)
                            startDateTV.append(regDt)
                            seqTV.append(seq)

                            text +=  i+" "+ startDateTv.text.toString()
                            startDate.text +=  text //change to this
                            println(startDateTV.toString() // put it here
                        }
                        authstatus.text = authstatusTV.toString()
                       
                        
                    }
```

Comment: firstly, the startDate.text += i +""+ startDateTv.toString line is not a format in kotlin. next, the result of the println in the for loop creates a triangle pattern. the first line is one record, 2nd line 2 record, 3rd line 3 record until the last line of array, this is im trying to figure out why it happens, bcs it always takes the first result until the end of the array

Comment: try now ! its toString() , if startDateTV is textView the try startdatetv.text.toString()

Comment: or you can iterate through the array by creating new for loop and putting i in the index number